# routerLinkActive remain active even when other link is clicked

Tags: angular

```
<ul>
 <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/">One</a></li>
 <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/somewhere">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem with is, that when the `Two` link is clicked, the `active` class applied to both links - the `One` link remain highlighted... Why is this happening, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"`

```ts
<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

Comment: Thanks a lot  buddy!

Comment: @vurrd, you should accept the answer as it is the correct solution

Comment: I know, it just says I need 5 mins to wait. don't worry :)

Comment: Hi. I know this is an old question,but I'd like to make an enquiry on how to make the 1st router link in a series of them remain active even after clicking other links.

Comment: @randomcoder66785 I'd suggest to create a new question with more details about what you try to accomplish